# Error running 'All in project01 (1)': No junit.jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea-2020

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VbiQ.png)

I don't know why I can't run all test()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the junit.jar in order to use junit to test your apps.
Go [here](https://junit.org/junit5/) and download your desired version.

Comment: when I delete .idea,  I can't  run call test() in project, but I  cant  in Module

Comment: why u delete .idea?

Comment: I want to solve a  problem，someone say delete .idea,then I can't run all test()